# How to create a module on a CentOS cluster

Tags: bash, shell, software-installation, environment-variables

I would like to create a module on a CentOS 6 cluster (e.g. `module load gcc-4.7.2`).  Basically, I have no clue how modules work.  Are there any good tutorials illustrating this or could someone provide a "Hello World" type tutorial?  I have looked at the `module` man page and it is not particularly useful.  I am having trouble finding good documentation online. What other resources are available to create modules?

Comment: Are there existing modules on the cluster you can look at?

Comment: Yes, basically I have no clue how modules work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [modulefile](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/modulefile.html) man page is probably of more use to you than the `module` man page.

A search for "environment module examples" yields [this page](http://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/Environment-Modules), which seems to have some good examples.  I think it addresses most of your questions:

> If I install a program from source, how do I make it available to load it as a module?

Install the package somewhere and then write a modulefile to modify the PATH (and other environment variables) accordingly.

> How do I change the environmental variables (e.g. PATH, LIBRARY_PATH) when a module is loaded?

Via the `setenv` command, examples of which you will find in that linked article.

> How do I execute associated shell commands, when a module is loaded (e.g. inform the user of default settings)?

Not sure what you're asking here.

> How do I load dependent modules when the module is loaded?

By using the `module` command in your modulefile.  As documented in the `modulefile(4)` man page:

> module [ sub-command ] [ sub-command-args ]
>
> Contains the same sub-commands as described in the module(1) man page
>   in the Module Sub-Commands section. This command permits a modulefile
>   to load or remove other modulefiles. No checks are made to ensure that
>   the modulefile does not try to load itself. Often it is useful to have
>   a single modulefile that performs a number of module load commands.
>   For example, if every user on the system requires a basic set of
>   applications loaded, then a core modulefile would contain the
>   necessary module load commands.